# Bilinear Interpolation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, interpolation

For a project I am doing I need to interpolate a value (interest rate)based on 2 dimensions ('days since 1900' and yield)

I currently have the following code where f is the interpolated value:

```
declare @rates table (
    days int,
    yield int,
    rate decimal(18,6)
)

insert into @rates (days,yield,rate)
values (1,30,0.1),
(1,90,0.2),
(3,30,0.2),
(null,3,90,0.4)

declare @data table(
    id int,
    days int,
    yield int)

insert into @data(id,date,days,yield) values
(1,2,60)


select r.*
-- calculation below does not work if x or y ends up being the same 
    -- (because they all cancel each other out)
,finalinterp = ((f11/((x2 - x1)*(y12 - y11)))*(x2 - x)*(y12 - y))
+ ((f21/((x2 - x1)*(y22 - y21)))*(x - x1)*(y22 - y))
+ ((f12/((x2 - x1)*(y12 - y11)))*(x2 - x)*(y - y11))
+ ((f22/((x2 - x1)*(y22 - y21)))*(x - x1)*(y - y21))

from
(
select id,d.days as x,isnull(x1,x2) x1 ,isnull(x2,x1) x2,d.yield as y,
ISNULL(y11,y12) y11,ISNULL(y12,y11) y12,ISNULL(y21,y22) y21,ISNULL(y22,y21) y22,
r11.rate as f11,
r12.rate as f12,
r21.rate as f21,
r22.rate as f22

from @data d
cross apply
(   
    select MAX(r.days)  as x1 from @rates r1
    where r.days <= d.days
) xt1
cross apply
(
    select MIN(r.days)  as x2 from @rates r1
    where days >= d.days
) xt2
cross apply
(
    select MAX(yield) as y11 from @rates r1
    where r1.days = isnull(x1,x2)
    and yield <= d.yield
) yt1
cross apply
(
    select MIN(yield) as y12 from @rates r1
    where r1.days = isnull(x1,x2)
    and yield >= d.yield
) yt2
cross apply
(
    select MAX(yield) as y21 from @rates r1
    where r1.days = isnull(x2,x1)
    and yield <= d.yield
) yt3
cross apply
(
    select MIN(yield) as y22 from @rates r1
    where r1.days = isnull(x2,x1)
    and yield >= d.yield
) yt4
left outer join @rates r11 on r11.mdays = isnull(x1,x2) and r11.yield = ISNULL(y11,y12)
left outer join @rates r12 on r12.mdays = isnull(x1,x2) and r12.yield = ISNULL(y12,y11)
left outer join @rates r21 on r21.mdays = isnull(x2,x1) and r21.yield = ISNULL(y21,y22)
left outer join @rates r22 on r22.mdays = isnull(x2,x1) and r22.yield = ISNULL(y22,y21)
) r
```

Currently this works for a properly interpreted value however if the value actually exists (e.g. if I set data.yield = 90 or data.days = 1), thus doesn't need to be interpolated, it falls apart as it tries to do a divide by zero.

Can someone figure out how to make it work in this condition?

Also is there a more efficient way of doing this? In the real world there is a whole mashup of other tables in the same query so the more concise the better

Thanks

Comment: Depending on the requirements for interpolation, it is possible that the whole basis of your query is questionable. If you need to do this accurately, interpolating yields or interest rates requires linear interpolation on durations (as you are attempting to do) but requires GEOMETRIC interpolation on the yield.

Comment: Is that because the 'y' or yield points may not be the same for the two 'x' (durations) points? Do you know of any useful links as I tried but couldn;t find anything

Comment: It is because yields are compound interest, rather than simple interest. So the yield on a half year is (1+i)^1/2 -1 rather than i/2. Google for calculating compound interest; or actuarial interest; or loan or APR regulations. I haven't done these searches myself, but believe they should throw up relevant material.

Comment: Have confirmed with clients and straight linear in both dimensions is ok for this particular system. Thanks for the info anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer below for anyone interested. Haven't performance tested.

If x is less than x1, x1 value is used and so on for x > x2 and y.

```
declare @rates table (
    mdate datetime,
    mdays int,
    yield int,
    rate decimal(18,6)
)

insert into @rates (mdate,mdays,yield,rate)
values (null,1,30,0.23),
    (null,1,90,0.36),
    (null,31,30,0.25),
    (null,31,90,0.37)

declare @data table(
    did int,
    ddate datetime,
    ddays int,
    yield int)


insert into @data(did,ddate,ddays,yield) values
(1,null,32,30)


select r2.*,
f = ((f11/(isnull(nullif(x2 - x1,0),1) * isnull(nullif(y12 - y11,0),1))) * isnull(convert(float,nullif(x2 - x,0)),0.5) * isnull(convert(float,nullif(y12 - y,0)),0.5))
 + ((f21/(isnull(nullif(x2 - x1,0),1) * isnull(nullif(y22 - y21,0),1))) * isnull(convert(float,nullif(x - x1,0)),0.5) * isnull(convert(float,nullif(y22 - y,0)),0.5))
 + ((f12/(isnull(nullif(x2 - x1,0),1) * isnull(nullif(y12 - y11,0),1))) * isnull(convert(float,nullif(x2 - x,0)),0.5) * isnull(convert(float,nullif(y - y11,0)),0.5))
 + ((f22/(isnull(nullif(x2 - x1,0),1) * isnull(nullif(y22 - y21,0),1))) * isnull(convert(float,nullif(x - x1,0)),0.5) * isnull(convert(float,nullif(y - y21,0)),0.5))
from
    (
        select 
        case when x > x2 then x2
            when x < x1 then x1
            else x end as x,
        case when y > y22 then y22
            when y < y11 then y11
            else y end as y,
        x1,x2,y11,y12,y21,y22,f11,f12,f21,f22
    from
    (
        select did,ddays as x,isnull(x1,x2) x1 ,isnull(x2,x1) x2,d.yield as y,ISNULL(y11,y12) y11,ISNULL(y12,y11) y12,ISNULL(y21,y22) y21,ISNULL(y22,y21) y22,
        r11.rate as f11,
        r12.rate as f12,
        r21.rate as f21,
        r22.rate as f22

        from @data d
        cross apply
        (   
        select MAX(mdays)  as x1 from @rates r1
        where mdays <= d.ddays
        ) xt1
    cross apply
    (
        select MIN(mdays)  as x2 from @rates r1
        where mdays >= d.ddays
    ) xt2
    cross apply
    (
        select MAX(yield) as y11 from @rates r1
        where r1.mdays = isnull(x1,x2)
        and yield <= d.yield
    ) yt1
    cross apply
    (
        select MIN(yield) as y12 from @rates r1
        where r1.mdays = isnull(x1,x2)
        and yield >= d.yield
    ) yt2
    cross apply
    (
        select MAX(yield) as y21 from @rates r1
        where r1.mdays = isnull(x2,x1)
        and yield <= d.yield
    ) yt3
    cross apply
    (
        select MIN(yield) as y22 from @rates r1
        where r1.mdays = isnull(x2,x1)
        and yield >= d.yield
    ) yt4
    left outer join @rates r11 on r11.mdays = isnull(x1,x2) and r11.yield = ISNULL(y11,y12)
    left outer join @rates r12 on r12.mdays = isnull(x1,x2) and r12.yield = ISNULL(y12,y11)
    left outer join @rates r21 on r21.mdays = isnull(x2,x1) and r21.yield = ISNULL(y21,y22)
    left outer join @rates r22 on r22.mdays = isnull(x2,x1) and r22.yield = ISNULL(y22,y21)
) r
)r2
```